# GameMaker Studio 2 при переходе в комнату у объекта сбрасывается физика

Tags: game-maker

При переходе в новую комнату, на "постоянном" объекте выключается физика:

> Can not set the physics property for object "objHero", as physics have not been enabled for this object.

Answer (score 0):

Достаточно включить физику в комнате и проблема тут же исчезнет.

Включается в свойствах комнаты вот здесь:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]